# Ejecutar expresion cuando termine de traer los datos mediante Http AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

Estoy tratando de hacer que cuando le doy `click` al `checkbox` se ejecute una expresión cuando halla terminado de traer los `datos` de la función `getUsers()`, aparentemente funciona bien.

Pero entonces lo que quiero hacer es **desactivar** o **inhabilitar** el `checkbox` hasta que no halla terminado de cargar 1 primer llamado a la petición. Es decir que no puedan dar mas `click` hasta que halla traído los **datos**, **registros**.

PD: Si tienes un servicio que demora mucho tiempo 30 segundos o mas, entonces que **desactive** el `checkbox` o alguna otra forma para evitar que le den `click` al checkbox

```js
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
    app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $q, $http) {

        $scope.getUsers = function() {
            return $q(function(resolve,reject) {
                $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(function(res) {
                    $scope.users = res.data;
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        };

        $scope.filterUsers = function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $scope.getUsers().then(function() {
                    console.log("Termino de traer los datos");
                });
            });           
        }

        $scope.getUsers();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular-aria.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular-messages.js"></script>
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>

 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
 <div flex="30" layout="row" layout-align="end center">                
        <md-checkbox class="md-color-blue" style="margin: 0;" ng-model="filterUser" ng-click="filterUsers()" aria-label="user filter">
         Filtrar usuarios
        </md-checkbox>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Crees que te funcionaria que cuando le des click al check se desactive y cuando los datos se carguen se vuelva a activar?

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez Si eso es lo que quiero.

Comment: Jquery o solo js?

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Agregale el atributo ng-disabled a tu check:

```
<md-checkbox class="md-color-blue" style="margin: 0;" ng-model="filterUser" ng-click="filterUsers()" aria-label="user filter" ng-disabled="disable"> Filtrar usuarios </md-checkbox>
```

declara la variable disable y si esta es verdadera se desactivara y si es falsa se activara el check.

```
$scope.disable = true;
```

Y solo debes agregar que cuando se ejecute filterUsers se ponga el valor de `disable` en **false** y cuando se carguen los datos se ponga en **true**.

```
$scope.filterUsers = function() { 
$scope.disable = false;
setTimeout(function() { 
   $scope.getUsers().then(function() { 
    console.log("Termino de traer los datos");
$scope.disable = true;
     });  
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Nota: nunca he usado angular ni se declarar variables por si ves algún error tonto..